# How to compile against a different OSX SDK version than the installed one?

Tags: xcode, macos, clang, cross-compiling, macos-sierra

I am currently on OSX 10.12.6 (Sierra) but i would like to build binaries for 10.8 (Mavericks).

I am building a console application using the `clang` compiler. I have installed the 10.8 SDK at a location my disk.

However I cannot figure out the right combination of flags and options to actually link against the 10.8 SDK rather than the 10.12 one. I have tried with the following `CFLAGS` set by to no avail: `MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.8 --sysroot=/path/toMacOSX10.8.sdk/` but to no avail.

What must I do to compile for the SDK 10.8 ?

Comment: You want to build using the 10.8 SDK? Just setting the **deployment target** to "10.8 or above" isn't enough?

Comment: @NicolasMiarihow do i set the deployment target? i'm not using xcode i'm in the console

Comment: No idea; I always use Xcode. Why did you tag your question with [xcode]?

Comment: @NicolasMiari well because it's (`libSystem.B.dylib`) is a library installed by xcode and i had to navigate around the xcode paths in order to setup the new library and so on. I figured someone who has deep knowledge of xcode might be able to help here